# UICollectionView Horizontal Scrolling - cells ordered into columns instead of rows

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection View that I made horizontal scrolling. It has 3 rows and 5 columns. Once I enabled horizontal scrolling the cells fill up going down the columns instead of across the rows. For example i have an array 1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16 that i am using to fill my collection view. The cells would look like this

```
1,4,7,10,13,16
2,5,8,11,14
3,6,9,12,15
```

How can I fix this.

Answer (score 0):

That's the default behavior of horizontal.If you want you can sort the array in some way so it'll be displayed the way you want it.

Like this:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
var horizontalSortedArray = [Int]()
let columns = 5
let rows = 3
for i in 0..<columns {
    for j in 0..<rows {
        horizontalSortedArray.append(array[j*columns+i])
    }
}
print(horizontalSortedArray)
// [1, 6, 11, 2, 7, 12, 3, 8, 13, 4, 9, 14, 5, 10, 15]
```

Now if you use this new array as your data source in horizontal mode it'll be displayed like this:

```
1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5
6 ,7 ,8 ,9 ,10
11,12,13,14,15
```

Comment: what if my array isnt always the same amount of rows and columns. Because i want the collection view to fill up across the rows until they are full. Once full the next row starts but when three rows are full a new column is formed and the user can now scroll to the side to see the new columns